# Replace new line with space in variable Javascript before function

Tags: javascript, function, replace, line-breaks

I have the following code snipplet:

```
<script>
    var textstring = 
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. 
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.';

function insertNewLines(textstr, nos) {

var resulttext = '';
textstr = textstr.replace("\n", "<br />");
while (textstr.length > 0) {

resulttext += textstr.substring(0, nos) + '<br/>';
textstr = textstr.substring(nos);

}
```

The text in textstring is 2 rows i.e. there is a \r\n seperating the first from the second row. 
When I call the function it gives me an error even before I get the the replace part. (Debugger says that the block is not closed correctly because of the line break)

Is there a way I can get around that? I just need to get rid of the linebreak or even better keep it but let the script run correctly.

Thanks for all your help.

TheVagabond

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket for the function after the while loop (`}`).

Comment: And literal newlines in `'` or `"` quoted strings are not valid in JavaScript unless you escape them with a backslash. (They're valid in ES2015's template literals.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic syntax errors in that code:

1. You cannot have a newline in a string literal unless you escape it with a backslash. (You can in an ES2015 template literal, but not a string literal.) If you do, the newline is **not** included in the string. Use `\r\n` instead.
2. You're missing the closing `}` on the function

Aside from that, though, there's no need for the loop; JavaScript's `replace` can accept a regular expression with the `g` flag (for "global"), so:

```js
var textstring =
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.\r\nCum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.';

function insertNewLines(textstr, nos) {
    return textstr.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />");
}

console.log(insertNewLines(textstring));
```

I've replaced the literal newline with a `\r\n`, and then replaced the loop with the single call to `replace`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works!

Answer (score -1):

First deifine your sting lilke this,

```
var textstring ='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.\
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.';
```

And add one bracket to your function, it should work.

```
function insertNewLines(textstr, nos) {

var resulttext = '';
textstr = textstr.replace("\n", "<br />");
while (textstr.length > 0) {

resulttext += textstr.substring(0, nos) + '<br/>';
textstr = textstr.substring(nos);

}
}
```

Comment: No, because there are no longer any newlines in the string. The escaped newline is not included in the string.

Answer (score -1):

Newlines in JavaScript string should be escaped with an backslash(`\`).

Your variable `textstring` needs too be updated as shown below.

```js
var textstring =
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. \
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.';

function insertNewLines(textstr, nos) {
  var resulttext = '';
  textstr = textstr.replace("\n", "<br/>");

  while (textstr.length > 0) {
    resulttext += textstr.substring(0, nos) + '<br/>';
    textstr = textstr.substring(nos);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, because there are no longer any newlines in the string. The escaped newline is not included in the string.

Answer (score -1):

You must escape the literal string with a backslash also there was no closing bracket. Below code is escaped with backslash and the script is working. However the output is what is you wanted is not checked.

```
var textstring = 
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo  ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.\
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.';

insertNewLines(textstring,2);
function insertNewLines(textstr, nos) {

var resulttext = '';
textstr = textstr.replace("\n", "<br />");
while (textstr.length > 0) {

resulttext += textstr.substring(0, nos) + '<br/>';
textstr = textstr.substring(nos);

 }
}
```